# List of scriptures translated by Max Muller

Tags: scripture, history, translation, max-muller

Translation of Hindu scriptures is not an easy task and requires a lot of knowledge and even experience in different domains. Linguistic expertise is not the only one required to do it. Many of the verses may have a variety of valid interpretations. Context of the verse also plays an important role.

[Max Muller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max_M%C3%BCller) is a person who translated Hindu scriptures. He [distorted](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/32980/did-max-m%C3%BCller-actually-distort-hindu-scriptures-in-his-translations) the actual content in his translations.

What are the list of Hindu scriptures translated by him? And into which language he translated?

Comment: I agree Max Muller distorted the actual content in his translations. No doubt about it.