# Why Hindu community treats Vivekananda as an authentic personality if he says (some) wrong things while preaching?

Tags: vivekananda

I know that Vivekananda is confused during early days. But, I am honestly feeling that he is not fully realised later or by the time of Chicago speech also. **This opinion, of me, may be due to my ignorance.** There may be some strong reason that I am unaware of.

For suppose you can consider the [words of Vivekanda](https://www.ramakrishnavivekananda.info/vivekananda/volume_4/writings_prose/on_professor_max_muller.htm) on Max Muller

> **The visit was really a revelation to me**......
>
> **It was neither the philologist nor the scholar that I saw, but a soul that is every day realising its oneness with the Brahman, a heart
> that is every moment expanding to reach oneness with the
> Universal**......
>
> **And what love he bears towards India! I wish I had a hundredth part of that love for my own motherland! Endued** .....
>
> **Max Müller is a Vedantist of Vedantists**. He has, indeed, caught the real soul of the melody of the Vedanta, in the midst of all its
> settings of harmonies and discords — the one light that lightens the
> sects and creeds of the world, the Vedanta, the one principle of which
> all religions are only applications ........... Is it a wonder that
> this **Western sage** does study and appreciate every new star in the
> firmament of Indian thought, before even the Indians themselves
> realise its magnitude?

and the [intention of Max Muller is clearly faulty](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/32955) by his own letters.

It is evident, atleast for me, that Vivekananda praised just for the sake of praising.

Why does Hindu community considered Vivekananda as an authentic personality keeping aside these discrepancies?

Comment: Request for down-voters: Please comment the reason for down-voting if possible.

Comment: Sounds more like a debate than a question. Besides, we are only interested in his preachings on vedas and sanatan, not other things. For these his thoughts have direct backing of vedas , gita etc. He's mere translator in his own words. He didn't start a new field of Sanatan.

Comment: @sbharti do you mean that Vivekananda is considered authentic only if he talks about Scriptures and from scriptures. Else he is like any other person?

Comment: @sbharti but my intention is not to start a debate. This question has been disturbing me for so many days.

Comment: @hanugm the HSE answer you cited was biased in itself.The letters cited in there were written in 1856 & 1866, but in 1888, he gave a series of lectures in Glasgow, in which he praised Hinduism over Christianity.Those lectures had infuriated the English clergy so much that he was accussed of blasphemy against Christianity, a severe accusation in those days.He was defeated in the election to the Boyden Chair of Sanskrit in Oxford due to lobbying of Evangelicals against him, who stated that he wasn't zealous enough to be qualified to the post.Read Mueller's biography before making any opinion.

Comment: @hanugm where did he say Max Muller was a Jeevan mukta

Comment: @hanugm initially Max Muller may have come with a bad intention. But as more and more he studied Hinduism and Vedas he was taken by it and he himself fell in deep awe and appreciation, where his soul was slowly moving towards God. Do you know how many Vedas have been read and translated by Max Muller, do you think all that reading will leave no effect?? will leave a man unchanged??

Comment: @hanugm read this https://swarajyamag.com/culture/what-india-taught-max-muller

Comment: @MrGreenGold This seems to be a valid reason. I will read the article.

Answer (score 2):

Great souls like Swami Vivekananda will very rarely publicly criticize others. They will praise the good points of another person in public. You can't judge a Vivekananda by our yardstick.

**No public criticism of others**

> Even after knowing the defects of others, one should not proclaim them
> to others – this is another passage in the Sruti.

**Linga Purana I.8.14**

Comment: But, in the passage, Vivekananda told that Max Muller is a foremost vedantist and also a Jivan Muktha. Are they true?

Comment: No, of course it is not literally true. Vivekananda was being polite to his host. I am sure even MM did not take such hyperbole seriously. Vivekananda knew that in 1900 England almost no one had any sympathy for Hinduism. MM also had no sympathy. Nevertheless his translations are not doctored ones. He was a honest translator. I can not say that of many modern Indologists. What would Vivekananda gain by annoying MM? MM whatever his intention ultimately did not do any damage to Hindus.